# El uso de "cosa que"

Tags: gramática

> Ayer estuve en la fiesta de Resurrección, cosa que estaba bien chula.

No sé si se puede usar “cosa que” en este contexto.

Comment: Creo que está bien.  "Cosa" se refiere a la fiesta.

Comment: It's correct. Congratulations.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Suena raro. "cosa que" suele usarse cuando se hace referencia a toda la oración precedente, no a un sustantivo en particular, ej. La fiesta fue un desastre, cosa que nadie esperaba (nadie esperaba que la fiesta fuera un desastre).

Comment: siendo quisquilloso, no sería mejor "cosa que estuvo" o incluso "cosa que fue"? estaba me suena raro aunque no sé por qué

Answer (score 4):

No parece correcto usar *cosa que* en este contexto. En principio es discutible, pero en la práctica, suena incorrecto porque *cosa*, en este tipo de oraciones, no remite al objeto directo sino a todo el evento anterior. Resumo lo que dice la NGLE ([44.8h](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SuNfrwdjPKhEFwBr) y siguientes).

El uso de *cosa que* es un ejemplo de grupo nominal en aposición. Este tipo de cláusula utiliza sobre todo palabras genéricas como *cosa, lugar, hecho, problema, asunto, idea, momento*, sin artículo. Estas palabras refieren a circunstancias nombradas inmediatamente antes. *Cosa*, como *hecho*, se refiere generalmente a toda la proposición anterior. En el ejemplo, esto sería el haber estado ayer en la fiesta, no la fiesta en sí.

Se podría usar *cosa* en un ejemplo similar diciendo:

> *Ayer estuve en la fiesta de Resurrección, cosa que sorprenderá a los que me conocen (porque nunca voy a esa clase de fiestas).*

Es decir, la cosa en cuestión es *que ayer estuve en la fiesta de Resurrección*. En vez de *cosa* podría usar *hecho* (un poco más formal) o el pronombre relativo neutro (es decir, *lo que* o *lo cual*).

Si quisiera referirme directamente a la fiesta, no usaría *cosa que* sino simplemente *que* o *la cual*:

> *Ayer estuve en la fiesta de Resurrección, que estuvo bien chula.*
>   *Ayer estuve en la fiesta de Resurrección, la cual se celebra cada año con una procesión.*